# How to delete messages with discord bot

Tags: python, discord

I made a small discord bot, and I need him to delete a message from the writer and then post something. When I use @bot.event it works fine but it's the only thing working in code(only the delete part works). And how to use `ctx.message.delete`?

```
@bot.command(aliases=["IDC"])
async def idc(ctx):
ctx.channel.send("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/586526210469789717/838335535944564756/Editor40.mp4")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to save the channel for later use.

```py
@bot.command(aliases=["IDC"])
async def idc(ctx): 
  chn = ctx.channel
  await ctx.message.delete()
  await chn.send("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/586526210469789717/838335535944564756/Editor40.mp4")
```

Your bot will need the delete messages permission.

**EDIT**:
This will also work, but it is recommended to use the first way as it can be faster.

```py
@bot.command(aliases=["IDC"])
async def idc(ctx): 
  await ctx.send("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/586526210469789717/838335535944564756/Editor40.mp4")
  await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: @TadeasGrohmi Can you mark this answer as correct?